# edit text in uiwebview

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, annotations

I am developing an iPad application which loads ppt, pdf,doc through webview.
I want to allow user to add annotations (freehand annotation, text annotation, audio annotation) as an inline text when they view the files through webview.

Answer (score 0):

i now this is old question but also face this problem for a long period so i got solution and i think i have to tell you this thing.
all thing you want in uiwebview you can do on uiwebview external layer that called `uiwebview.scrollView` use this instead of uiwebview for annotation you can write on this view.